# let $a$ be a positive number then find the range of the function :

Tags: calculus

> let $a$ be a positive number then find the range of the function (Without derivative):
>
> $$f(x)=x+a+\sqrt{x^2+a}$$

Comment: Have you tried?  Consider first, $x > 0$, is the function increasing, decreasing, or neither?  Estimate its value for large $x$ (much greater than $a$).  Now consider $x < 0$ for small and large (absolute) values of $x$.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The function is continuous everywhere, and defined everywhere since it is the sum of two continuous functions ($x+a$ and $\sqrt{x^2+a}$).

Now, if you let $x$ go to $+\infty$, $f(x)$ goes to $+\infty$.

And at $-\infty$, notice that:
$$f(x) = \frac{(x+a)^2-x^2-a}{x+a-\sqrt{x^2+a}} = \frac{2ax+a^2-a}{x+a-\sqrt{x^2+a}} = \frac{2ax+a^2-a}{x+a+x\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{x^2}}}$$
Which tends to $a$.
By the intermediary value theorem, $f$ must take every value between $a$ and $+\infty$, so the range is:$$(a, +\infty)$$

Edit: I think one way to see the range clearly is to write this function as:
$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\left(\sqrt{x^2+a}+x\right)+a,\quad &x \geq 0\\
\left(\sqrt{|x|^2+a}-|x|\right)+a,\quad &x<0 \end{cases}$

It is clear that $f(x)>a$

Comment: Why can the range not be some larger set?

Comment: I somehow assumed the function was increasing. Thanks for the remark! I edited my post. I've been editing my post non-stop. I keep on seeing silly mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$y=x+a+\sqrt{x^2+a}$$
We get
$$x=\frac{a}{2(a-y)}+\frac{a-y}{2}$$

So we have solution except when $y=a$.

Because we have taken square, we need to check that $y-a-x$ is non-negative.

We have
$$y-x-a=\frac{y-a}{2}+\frac{a}{2(y-a)}$$
is positive when $y>a$, and negative when $y<a$.

Hence, the range is $(a,+\infty)$.

Comment: $f$ is continuous, so the range must be a (single) interval.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the equation $$y=x+a+\sqrt{x^2+a}$$

for $x$ we get
$$x=\frac{(y-a)^2-a}{2(y-a)}$$

Edit:

$y>a$ because $$y-a=x+\sqrt{x^2+a}>0$$
for all $x$.

Comment: $f$ is continuous, so the range must be a (single) interval.

Answer (score 1):

for negative x: $-x= |x|=\sqrt{x^2}<\sqrt{x^2+a}$ and $f(x)>a$

$f(x)$ obtaine any value more then $a$:
$$a+\epsilon =x+a+\sqrt{x^2+a}$$
$$\epsilon =x+\sqrt{x^2+a}$$
$$(\epsilon -x)^2 =x^2+a$$
$$\epsilon^2-2x\epsilon +x^2 =x^2+a$$
$$\epsilon^2-2x\epsilon =a$$
$$x=\frac{\epsilon^2+a}{2\epsilon}$$

So the range is $(a;+\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

So you are interested for which $b\in \mathbb R$ there is such $x$ that $$x+a+\sqrt{x^2+a}=b$$
so $$x^2+a = (b-a-x)^2$$
so $$x = {(b-a)^2-a\over 2(b-a)}$$ if $b\ne a$. Also we have $x+a+\sqrt{a}\leq b$ so

$${(b-a)^2-a\over 2(b-a)}+a+\sqrt{a}\leq b$$ so we have $$2\sqrt{a}\leq {(b-a)^2+a\over b-a}$$
so $b>a$. So the range is subset of $(a,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Solving the equation for $x$:

$$y=x+a+\sqrt{x^2+a}$$

$$x=\frac{2ya-y^2}{2(a-y)} \implies y\neq a$$

Since $f$ is continuous and $f(0)>0$ range of $f$ is $(a,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong:

1) For $x \ge 0$: $f(x) \ge a+√a.$

Not bounded above:

Range$_1 = [a+√a,\infty)$

2) For $x \lt 0:$

$f(x) = x + a + |x|\sqrt{1+a/x^2} \gt a.$

Note: $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} f(x) =a.$

Hence Range$_2 = (a,a+√a).$

Hence Range : $(a,\infty).$